Which colouring won't stain my AB Silicone
I made an aneurysm model out of AB silicone, which is pretty soft. I'm planning to do some fluid experiments with it by running water through the model. I want to use colored water (or maybe some kind of dye) to visualize the flow inside.
My plan is to use a syringe to inject the coloring into the water tube, not directly into the model itself. But I'm worried the coloring might stain the silicone.
Any ideas on what kind of coloring I should use to avoid staining? Thanks!Hey everyone,


Removed the duplicate text.

Test the silicone with various dye possibilities and see which ones stain or don't. Food dyes, chemical dyes etc  (mind you food dyes are chemical, just referring to source...
